# How to make jQuery sortable plugin working with list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to put [this jQuery sortable plugin](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) into my bootstrap list-group-item. I just want to put normal drag-drop/sortable option, no effect/animation. That's why, I just made my code like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group item-list">
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group item-list">

</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.item-list').sortable();
```

But, it could not drop item from first `ul.item-list` to second `ul.item-list`! How to make it working?

[Fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/73c0a9x5/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need more than just calling .sortable()?

This example seem to do what you want to do, they use ol rather than ul tags with li items

http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#connected

Then simply "show code" to get the example

*******Update*********

Working code:

```
$('.item-list').sortable({
    group: 'list-group',
    pullPlaceholder: false,
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73c0a9x5/7/)

Comment: I edited the fiddle, have a look it seems to drop items in the list now. Think you need the "group" option

Comment: ol and ul should not be the fact. I have also applied other codes by their "show code" which also don't work. You can see my this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/73c0a9x5/2/

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstood. I updated the fiddle you gave here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/73c0a9x5/7/). I seem able to drag items from list 1 to 2 ?